# Firestore no permissions to execute operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set up rules in Firestore where everyone can read from each other's content if they are authenticated into the application but only owners of documents can create, write, update or delete them.

I have set up the following rules in Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database} {
    match /codes/{userID} {
      allow create, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userID;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My Firestore structure is:

```
Collection 'codes' > Document 'BNhBibYZ0ThCNCH2gzPRufFsIk22' > nothing in here
```

My request is:

```
firestore()
  .collection('codes')
  .doc(this.state.userID)
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot) {
      let testObj = {"hello": "world"} 
      firestore().collection('codes').doc(this.state.userID).set(testObj);
    }
  });
```

The output I receive is: `Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact value of `this.state.userID` at the time of the query?  (And are you sure you want to use `onSnapshot()` instead of `get()`?)

Comment: Given your code structure I'm fairly sure it's the `onSnapshot` that's failing, which means that from Firestore's perspective you aren't authenticated. Can you double-check that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is non-null and that `currentUser.uid` matches `this.state.userID`?

Comment: @DougStevenson I can confirm that this.state.userID is `BNhBibYZ0ThCNCH2gzPRufFsIk22`, but just in case I tried hard-coding it as well. The issue still persists. I substituted `onSnapshot()` with `get()` but it is still the same.
@MichaelBleigh exactly before the set function, I have printed out the auth().currentUser.uid and it matches the document's name which is `BNhBibYZ0ThCNCH2gzPRufFsIk22`. I tried leaving only the `.set` function but still I have permission issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following functions I created to do this

```
function isUserAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth.uid != null; 
}

function belongsTo(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /codes/{userId} {
      allow read : if isUserAuthenticated();
      allow create : if belongsTo(userId);
      allow update: if belongsTo(userId);
      allow delete: if belongsTo(userId);
    }

    /* Functions */
    function isUserAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null; 
    }

    function belongsTo(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

**Accept as answer if it works for you. Available for more questions in the comments.**

Comment: Interestingly enough, this partially helped me. I was missing `/documents`  after `match /databases/{database}`. After that, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Great. I'm happy I helped